# JQuery Datatable - How to specify column sorting when the order and number of columns is not fixed

Tags: jquery, datatable

Currently i am specifying the column attributes for datatable as below in jsp.

```
"aoColumns":
    [
        {
            "bSortable": false,
            "bSearchable": false,
            "sWidth": "90px"
        },
            {"bSortable": true, "sWidth": "105px"},
            {"bSortable": true, "sWidth": "72px" }
        }
    ]
```

We added a feature where the user can change his/her preferences for columns to remove/add columns in search results (this is not show/hide). If second column is removed and have only two columns in search resuls (first and third) it is failing. If I removed the second column attribute for `aoColumns`, then it is working fine.

Is there any way I can define the column attributes by column name/title so that only if that specific column exists, those attributes will be applied to that column?

Comment: it is failing: how? try describing your problem again. this makes very little sense

Comment: Hi, By failing, i mean it does not display the data. It just displays the header columns. No visible error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can apply same sorting options always, and then hide columns using something like colVis plugin for datatables see http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/ColVis/theme.html.

I think that this plugin will apply standard settings and then hide some of the columns that should not be used for some users.

Jovan

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I am already using the bVis to make the column visible or hide. oTable-fnSettings-aoColumns bVisible.     Problem i am encontering is how to define the column attributes (width, sortable, searchable) dynamically in datatable where the number of columns, their order can change.